# Nodejs how response locals on each get view on app.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, layout, response, local-variables

I am trying to handle simple user information through cookies, this information is visible in my layout through res.render, but I saw it very tedious, since it will always be simple information and I would have to be doing it in each .get (), then in app.js I did this:

app.js

```
app.use(function(req,res, next){
  var cookies = req.cookies;
  if(!cookies.UserData){
    console.log('cookies no exists');
  }
  else{
    console.log('cookies');
    res.locals.user = cookies.UserData;
    next();
  }

});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

layout.ejs

```
<%- user.username %>
```

but "user" was not defined, but in my error.ejs When a 404 was generated, I put `"<%- user.username %>"` it in and it worked.

but it only works on 404 catches and not in general, what am I doing wrong? how I do this?

Comment: Put the code for your 404 handler here

Comment: @tbking ok, I put it

Comment: On stack overflow, you do NOT put answers into your question.  Questions are for questions and answers are for answers.  If you've solved your own problem, then put the solution in an answer to your question (yes, you can answer your own question).  Please edit your question to remove the answer and to remove the "solved" from the title - that's not how things roll here on stack overflow.  You can file your own answer and, after some time has passed, you can accept your own answer as the best answer to indicate to the community that you now have an answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right, it sounds logical, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I solved it

In my Router-level middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.use(function(req,res, next){
  var cookies = req.cookies;
  if(!cookies.UserData){
    console.log('cookies no exist');
  }
  else{
    console.log('cookies');
    res.locals.user = cookies.UserData;
    next();
  }
});
```

> **I put it first in the router-level middleware, above all the other http methods**